# Create associated array out of taxonomy terms

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to get associated array out of taxonomy slug and taxonomy name. I have this

```
foreach (get_terms('taxonomy') as $tax_term) {
        $taxonomy_slug = $tax_term->slug;
        $taxonomy_name = $tax_term->name;
}
```

The issue is, that these are just strings glued together, I don't know how to separate them :\ When I `print_r` them out I get:

`term1term2term3term4`...

What I need is a way to separate those, and then create array that will look like this:

```
Array(
['term_1'] => Term 1
['term_2'] => Term 2
...
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what is the value of $tax_term->slug ? and $tax_term->name ?

Comment: When I make `print_r($taxonomy_slug)` i get all the slugs as a single string - this is what bothers me. I cannot separate them :\

Comment: This means the $taxonomy_slug is the another array with the values as term1,term2,term3,term4 right? or just a single string term1term2term3term4.

Comment: Singe string term1term2term3term4

Comment: Ok and what is in $tax_term->name?

Comment: The string like in the one about but with names, glued together as a single string...

Comment: that means the word "term" right?

Comment: What part of 'glued together' is not understandable?

Answer (score 0):

As per your inputs in comments I have tried to find out the solution. Hope this will helps you.

```
$terms = array();
foreach (get_terms('taxonomy') as $tax_term) {
        $taxonomy_slug = $tax_term->slug;
        $taxonomy_name = $tax_term->name;
        $exploded = explode($taxonomy_name,$taxonomy_slug);
        foreach ($exploded as $termValue) {
            if (!empty($termValue)) {
                $terms[$taxonomy_name."_".$termValue] = ucfirst($taxonomy_name)." ".$termValue;
            }
        }
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($terms);
```